# Using npm modules with ES6 and Future of npm/bundlers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I use ES6 for a while and have no experience with npm or node.js.

I want to use some npm modules in my project using ES6.

I tried following and got an error

```
import {axios} from './axios.js';
```

*The requested module './axios.min.js' does not provide an export named 'axios'*

I am trying to use https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/dist/axios.js

I do not want to use `<script src="..."></script>` tag implementation. I want to to load it on demand with ES6 modules.

Is there any helper script to adapt npm modules to ES6 or any solution?

Comment: did you init your project, e.g. `npm init myProject`

Comment: I do not use npm nothing about node.js. So no npm init myProject

Comment: `nothing about node.js` - yet you've tagged the question with `node.js`

Comment: `Future of npm` - I think you have no idea what NPM is - it's the node package manager - and has nothing to do with import/export/require etc

Comment: "Do you think EcmaScript will replace npm modules in the near future?" — That's like asking if cars will replace petrol engines.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.I mean npm module bundlers like webpack. With ES6 modules and http2 are they still be useful? I really do not like bundlers running in the background compiling scripts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import {axios} from './axios.js';
```

would require Axios to have a named export like

```
export function axios(...params) { ... }
```

Axios does have a default export though, which you import without the curly braces:

```
import axios from './axios.js';
```

For imports to work in a browser, you need to declare the importing script with `type="module"`:

```
<script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
```

### Edit:

Checking that URL you gave it seems Axios does not provide an ECMAScript module at all. Importing the way I described will work as long as you're using something like webpack to bundle your scripts.

### Edit 2:

I have just filed an issue on the Axios repository regarding the topic: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1879

### Edit 3 (April 2021):

Three years forward, even Node.js supports ES Modules, but Axios seems stuck on an old code base that looks unlikely to *ever* get updated, which causes problems when you want to use Axios along with Vue.js 3/Vite build stack, or Svelte.

A 20% the size but not all the features (e.g. `interceptors` are missing) rewrite in ES6 including proper exports is available with [`redaxios`](https://github.com/developit/redaxios).

Answer (score 1):

```
import { default as axios } from 'axios';
```