# How to use axios with native es6 module?

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-modules

I am trying to import axios like `import * as axios from '/lib/axios.min.js';`  but it throwing error. also tried `import axios from '/lib/axios.min.js';` . but no luck.

My Script tag looks like below.

```
<script type="module" src="/js/api-service.js"></script>
```

Could anyone please suggest me how to axios with es6 modules properly ?

***Note:** Before marking it as duplicate, Kindly understand this question is not about using native modules. My question is about using axios with es6 modules through script tag and it's not working*

I want to work/load axios as module with script tag. the following question used to mark this as duplicate not answering my question. [Using npm modules with ES6 and Future of npm/bundlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316944/using-npm-modules-with-es6-and-future-of-npm-bundlers)

Comment: What does your `script` tag look like?

Comment: you use CDN instead <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>

Comment: The above is minimal example .. you can just copy paste and can check and Sorry @jhpratt I don't know like there's a rule that people will down-vote for not answering over 10 min..